# Alternate for default Web browser in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, browser

I want to use some other web browser for my application. Is there any alternate for default web browser in windows phone 7?

```
<phone:WebBrowser Source="{Binding webSource}" Navigated="MiniBrowser_Navigated" NavigationFailed="MiniBrowser_NavigationFailed" Loaded="MiniBrowser_Loaded" Navigating="MiniBrowser_Navigating" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,82,0,0" Name="MiniBrowser" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="680" Width="476" >
            </phone:WebBrowser>
```

My View Model:-

```
 public WebBrowserExampleViewModel()
        {
            goButton = new ReactiveAsyncCommand();
            goButton.Subscribe(x => {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(source))
                {
                    progressVisiblity = Visibility.Visible;
                    //webSource = "https://" + source;//"https://www.facebook.com/Burger.King.Turkiye";
                    webSource = source;
                }
            });
        }
```

But I want to use any other browser. Please let me any idea. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by any other browser here?

Comment: for example Chrome, Opera etc?